# Showing item from Json list while scanning QR code

Tags: c#, json, xamarin

I have list in JSON and im deserializing it. It looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "Nazwa": "Czekolada mleczna Sport & Fitness",
    "Opis": "Przykładowy opis produktu Czekolada mleczna Sport & Fitness",
    "Zdjecie": "https://www.friars.co.uk/images/lindt-gold-milk-chocolate-bar-p504-7263_image.jpg",
    "WW": 0.28,
    "WBT": 0.22,
    "Energia": 31.8125,
    "Tluszcz": 2.19375,
    "Weglowodany": 3.225,
    "Blonnik": 0.11875,
    "Bialko": 0.45625,
    "Zelazo": 0.1875,
    "Wapn": 15.5,
    "Code": "czokolate_1"
  },
  {
    "Nazwa": "Czekolada mleczna Sport & Fitness2",
    "Opis": "Przykładowy opis produktu Czekolada mleczna Sport & Fitness2",
    "Zdjecie": "https://vaya.in/recipes/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/Milk-Chocolate-1.jpg",
    "WW": 0.16,
    "WBT": 0.21,
    "Energia": 28.5625,
    "Tluszcz": 2.19375,
    "Weglowodany": 2.94375,
    "Blonnik": 0.4875,
    "Bialko": 0.34375,
    "Zelazo": 0.8125,
    "Wapn": 0,
    "Code": "czokolate_2"
  }
]
```

I'm using **ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms** to scan QR code. To handle result I have this code:

```
public Item item { get; set; }
```

```
public void Handle_OnScanResult(Result result)
        {
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
            {
                string code = item.Code;
                string wynik = result.Text;
                if (wynik == code) {
                    await Navigation.PushAsync(new ItemDetailPage(item.Nazwa, item.Opis, item.Zdjecie, item.WW, item.WBT, item.Energia, item.Tluszcz, item.Weglowodany, item.Blonnik, item.Bialko, item.Zelazo, item.Wapn, item.Code));
                    await DisplayAlert("Wyszukaj?", item.Nazwa, "OK");
                }
            });
        }
```

item.Code is value assigned to item in JSON list, and QR code has this value too if I use

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
            {
                string wynik = result.Text;
                    await DisplayAlert("Wyszukaj?", wynik, "OK");
                }
            });
```

It shows this value *"code"*. I want it to show detail page with all values (I have it but only when you click on item in list it sends all values of this item to ItemDetailPage)
**ItemPage**

```
async void OnItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            if (!(args.SelectedItem is Item item))
                return;

            await Navigation.PushAsync(new ItemDetailPage(item.Nazwa, item.Opis, item.Zdjecie, item.WW, item.WBT, item.Energia, item.Tluszcz, item.Weglowodany, item.Blonnik, item.Bialko, item.Zelazo, item.Wapn, item.Code));

            // Manually deselect item.
            ItemsListView.SelectedItem = null;
        }
```

**ItemDetailPage**

```
public ItemDetailPage(string Nazwa, string Opis, string Zdjecie, float WW, float WBT, float Energia, float Tluszcz, float Weglowodany, float Blonnik, float Bialko, float Zelazo, float Wapn, string Code)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            tytul.Title = Nazwa;
            nazwa.Text = Nazwa;
            opis.Text = Opis;
            foto.Source = ImageSource.FromUri(new Uri(Zdjecie));
            ww_item.Text = WW.ToString();
            wbt_item.Text = WBT.ToString();
            energia_item.Text = Energia.ToString();
            tluszcz_item.Text = Tluszcz.ToString();
            weglowodany_item.Text = Weglowodany.ToString();
            blonnik_item.Text = Blonnik.ToString();
            bialko_item.Text = Bialko.ToString();
            zelazo_item.Text = Zelazo.ToString();
            wapn_item.Text = Wapn.ToString();
        }
```

I want it to move to ItemDetailPage with item details which have same "code" value as QR code
OR
I want it to show ItemPage with only those items which have "code" value as QR code.
I tried using something like searchbar but I can't get it work with JSON list

Comment: are you asking how to find the Item(s) in a list that match the scanned code?

Comment: @Jason yes that's what I meant, sorry If I wasn't clear enough

Comment: Also there will be one item which match one QR code

Comment: I would suggest you to pass an item to `ItemDetailPage` instead of the detailed properties.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT i tried doing that but it never works for me, that's why i use detailed properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to select a single item from a list (assume `items` is a `List<Item>`)

```
using System.Linq;

var item = items.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Code == result.Text);
```

to select all matches

```
var allitems = items.Where(x => x.Code == result.Text).ToList();
```

Comment: I only have Observablecollection<Item> in ItemDetailPage

Comment: I tried what you said and now it looks like this:
```public ObservableCollection<Item> items { get; set; }```
```public void Handle_OnScanResult(Result result)
  {
   Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
   {
    var item = items.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Code = result.Text);
   });
  }```
And I have two errors that i cannot convert string to bool and this one:
*CS1662 C# Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type*

Comment: why are you doing this?  This is not a UI operation.  It is just finding the matching data in your list.  You can then pass that data to your UI page.  Also check for "=" vs "=="

Comment: Okay so i have something like this 
```public async void Handle_OnScanResult(Result result)
  {
   var item = items.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Code == result.Text);
   await Navigation.PushAsync(new ItemPage());
  }```
but I dont know where i should pass this data, To ItemPage or ItemsViewModel?

Comment: ItemDetailPage, I assume

Comment: okay so i did something like this (like i have in ItemPage which sends data on click) 
```public async void Handle_OnScanResult(Result result)
  {
   var item = items.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Code == result.Text);
   await Navigation.PushAsync(new ItemDetailPage(item.Nazwa, item.Opis, item.Zdjecie, item.WW, item.WBT, item.Energia, item.Tluszcz, item.Weglowodany, item.Blonnik, item.Bialko, item.Zelazo, item.Wapn, item.Code));
  }```
and I have this error when i scan qr code **System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: source'**

Comment: why don't you pass the entire Item instead of passing each field?  Regardless, you need to look at the stack trace of the exception to find the source of the error.  I would guess it's something to do with `foto.Source`

Comment: I followed some tutorials, thats why it looks like this. Also I checked the stack trace but i dont know what's wrong :/
[Image](https://i.imgur.com/4y2Emi6.png)

Comment: sorry, without seeing more of your code I can't help.

Comment: I don't even know what i should show you, I have also ItemDetailViewModel which looks like this ```public class ItemDetailViewModel : BaseViewModel
 {
  public Item Item { get; set; }
  public ItemDetailViewModel(Item item = null)
  {
   Title = item.Nazwa;
   Item = item;
  }
 }``` Can we pm somehow? I will share you my code on github and if you will be able to help me I can pay little bit. I really need that but I don't have idea how to do it right :/

Comment: if you post your github url I'll take a quick look

Comment: `items` is null in FullScanPage

Comment: further, do not check bin/obj files into git.  Use the VS template here: https://github.com/github/gitignore

Comment: Okay sorry, so.. why its null? i thought its taking data from list

Comment: You aren't passing the data into the scan page.  You either need to do that, or have the Scan page return its value to the ItemPage and do the list search there.

Comment: Okay i think 2nd option would be easier for me, so firstly i need to take result.Text to variable and then reuse it in ItemPage with "filtering" list view?